# iOS App Review rejected with review team comment - Metadata rejected

Tags: ios, metadata

My recent release was rejected with the following comment

> Metadata Rejected.
>
> "Thank you for your resubmission, however we were still not provided
>   with an OTP. In order for us to review your app, please provide an OTP
>   so that we may fully assess your app's features.
>
> Next Steps :
>
> To help us proceed with the review of your app, please provide a user
>   name and password in the App Review Information section for your app
>   in iTunes Connect."

My app has the following functionality for  access :

(1)by internal users [having emails restricted to the company domain] and

(2)by external users [any email id can be used but only Indian mobile number has to be used]

How do I clear this ?

Comment: This question is not about programming, rather about the review process of the App Store.

Answer (score -1):

in Itunesconnect, there is an option to provide username / password for ios App Review Information. So provide that.